# Set Quote Name by default to start with "QT-"

Tags: workflow, standard-objects

I have already written a workflow rule but it still allows me to save a name even if it does not start with "QT-". Below is the pic of my workflow rule. Just fyi, the workflow rule is activated.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is a validation rule and not a workflow. What do you want to do exactly? Throw an error if the user enters a name that does not start with "QT"? If so, then a validation rule is what you need. But if you want to add "QT" as a prefix to the name automatically, then a workflow is appropriate.

Comment: thank u... Lets say I want QT- as prefix. So I believe the field will already those prefix set before even the user starts entering anything into that field. right ? but still I am not able to get the prefix here with the workflow rule.

Comment: No, the workflow rule will match records with the QT- prefix and then do something else. It is the validation rule that will prevent a user saving a record that does not have the QT- prefix.

Comment: @JonathanHersh thank u very much.....So my validation rule should be  
**BEGINS("QT-", Name)** where Name is the field name of Quote. This does not work.